# Using a JSONResult in a C# function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a function which returns a JsonResult in the below way.

```
var attachments = (from a in ar.Attachments 
  select new { id = a.Id, filename = a.FileName }).ToArray(); 
var result = new
            {
                comments = "Some string",
                attachments = attachments
            };

        return this.Json(result);
```

I need to use this result in another class where I need to access the "comments" and "attachments". Here attachments is a string array and comments is a string. Please let me know how I can do this.

Comment: @slandau: Does the use case really matter?  What if he's trying to build a generalized helper library?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve this JSON info in your View?  If so, that's easy.

Comment: @Robert - not REALLY, but kind of. If he's misunderstand very simple c# operations, and the fact that he can return the string and array as a c# object to another c# function and have a MUCH easier time reading and working with the data, then I think he should know about it. And second, if he is returning this to a view with MVC, he should tag his question appropriately.

Comment: Hi.. This is an existing function (in the controller) whose result is being used on the client side. I need to reuse this function in my class which is server side. So, I have a c# function where I'm making a call to this funnction

Answer (score 1):

You could create a ViewModel for the result and then just reuse that class. All a ViewModel is, is just a POCO or DTO. The idea is that it gives you a different way to "look" at your data, nothing special really.

So you end up with 3 parts.

The get data method:

```
public CommentsViewModel GetViewModel()
{
    var attachments = 
        (from a in ar.Attachments 
        select new { id = a.Id, filename = a.FileName }).ToArray(); 
    var result = new CommentsViewModel
            {
                comments = "Some string",
                attachments = attachments
            };

    return result;
}
```

Your controller method:

```
public JsonResult Get()
{
    return this.Json(GetViewModel());
}
```

And your other method would just call GetViewModel() directly. This would separate this out a bit for you.

Comment: Hi.. This is an existing function (in the controller) whose result is being used on the client side. I need to reuse this function in my class which is server side. So, I have a c# function where I'm making a call to this funnction.

Comment: @Feroz so if I understand you correctly, you could create a method that returns the ViewModel object representing your data like I suggested by just changing you linq to select new ViewModelName{}. Then your existing method would just call this method and pass in the ViewModel result into this.Json(). That way the other part of your code that needs to work with the comments just work with the ViewModel. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Feroz If possible, consider a common method to generate the data. Returning the JSON is just a wrapper about that method; alternatively the data in the "raw form" can be accessed from the common method. Anonymous types don't have an accessible nominative type (e.g. must be lifted to `object` to be returned or passed), but a defined type (with static access, dynamic access, or `dynamic`) could be passed around trivially.

Comment: Many thanks for your interest. But I cant change the function which is returning the result. Its an existing one which is being used at many other places on the client side. I just need to take the JSONResult it is returning the way it is and my call now to the function is from the server side.

Comment: @Feroz Oh I see, sorry I couldn't be of much help for your needs.

Comment: I did this................... var data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myJSONResult.Data);............ I got the below result - "{\"comments\":\"As PA\",\"attachments\":[{\"id\":122,\"filename\":\"CPL_20009591_Blue hills.jpg\"}]}"............... Any idea on how I can programmatically get the Commenst and Attachments?

Comment: @Feroz I was just looking at the same thing myself as I found this interesting! Not yet no. It is a JsonjsonResult object that you get back right...just to confirm.

Comment: @Feroz I've posted another solution that I think will fit your needs using the dynamic data type.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is an answer that I believe should fit your needs using the `dynamic` type...

This is the method you call on the controller...I have put in 'hard coded' sample data as per your requirements for this example...I've removed the 's' from comments just because:

```
public JsonResult GetJsonData()
{
    var result = new
        {
            comment = "Some string",
            attachments = new string[]{"/folder/file-1.jpg", "/folder/file-2.jpg"}
        };

        return this.Json(result);
}
```

The code that calls the controller action directly and reads the JsonResult:

```
dynamic result = GetJsonData().Data;

//var comment will result in a string which equals "Some string" in this example
var comment = result.comment;

//var attachments will result in a string[] which is equal to new string[]{"/folder/file-1.jpg", "/folder/file-2.jpg"}
var attachments = result.attachments;
```